# Is a point in or out of an irregular pollygon?

Tags: geometry

Two Dimensions.

I have a list of N points which are the corners of an irregular, non-intersecting polygon in clockwise order.

For any other point, is it inside or outside the polygon?

Is there an algorithm for this?

Comment: Draw a line segment connecting the given point to another point far out (clearly outside the polygon for example because one of its coordinates is off the scale). Then calculate how many sides of the polygon this point intersects with. If an odd number, then the point was inside. If an even number, then it is outside.

Comment: Smart! So basically check each side for intersection and keep a tally. This is probably going to annoy you mathematicians, but what is the formula for if a segment intersects another segment?

Comment: The proper algorithm partly depends on what you mean by "inside or outside" the polygon. This is clear for a simple, non-self-intersecting polygon, due to the Jordan curve theorem, but if the polygon can intersect itself there are some strange cases. Please clarify: do you mean simple (non-self-intersecting) polygons? If not, clarify what "inside" means.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I meant a non-intersecting polygon. but one that can have obtuse or acute angles.

Comment: The segment $L$ from the point of interest $P_0=(x_0,y_0)$ to that far out point $P=(x,y_0)$ (with $x$ very larger) can be chosen to be parallel to $x$-axis. Then for another line segment connecting $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ to 
$P_2=(x_2,y_2)$ can intersect $L$ only if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are on opposite sides of $y_0$. Only when this is the case will you do need to do a bit of linear algebra. CAVEAT: If $y_0$ coincides with the $y$-coordinate of one of the vertices, then you need to exercise some care. Basically you need to be careful not to overcount.

Comment: @RoryDaulton: I think that "clockwise order" strongly hints at a non-self-intersecting polygon. Your request for clarity is, of course, still ok.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I thought of that, but a polygon could be described as "clockwise" while winding two or more times around a given point. If it winds twice, is the point inside or outside? I have seen both definitions used. Your comment is still excellent.

Answer (score 0):

If there are self-intersections, the algorithm doesn't collapse; it simply gives figures like below (that may remind of Matisse...): the blue colored regions represent the set of points that are considered as "inside" the polygonal shape (of course, one shouldn't any more distinguish an "inside" and an "outside".

The fact that a region is filled  is linked to the parity of the winding number. Let me explain it plainly.

Let us take, in the plane assimilated to the complex plane, a reference point $z_0$. Let us consider the function $w(z)=arg(z-z_0)/(2 \pi)$. When $z$ follows the (closed) contour, the difference of values of $w$ between the beginning and the end of the contour is the (signed) number of times the contour has "turned around" point $z_0$. *Colored regions are those with an odd winding number*.

For a rigorous mathematical definition  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number.

[image])